# applying a GPO to all users for a specific server

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, terminal-server, folder-redirection

first time writer here.

My situation is as follows:
we have an active directory, that is more or less organized. All users are in a single OU, and working on a Terminalserver (WINS 2012R2), lets call him "TS01". Now we are setting up a new TS, "TS02", with WINS 2019, and wanted to change a few details. One of which is instead of using userprofile disks we wanted each user to get their home directory into another, specific path (default is C:\Users...), specifically D:\Users...

Basically a simple folder redirection. The only thing is, that if I apply a GPO to that OU the folder will be also redirected on the server they are currently working on, what we want to evade at any cost. So the next thought was to put the Server in a single OU and apply the GPO to the device. Which did not word as intended.

The GPO gets configured without issues, but when looking into the gpresult, the GPO does not get listed and the folders are not redirected.

Is there a way to set up a GPO that will work for all users, but only when they log into this specific TS02 server? Answers are greatly appreciated.

tl;dr: how do i set up a folder redirection GPO of all homedirectory folders for all users, but only if they log in to a specific server?

Comment: `The GPO gets configured without issues` if the GPO is not working and is not applying in gpresult, what does it mean to say it is configured without issue? Also you need to confirm that Group Policy *loopback processing* is enabled if you want user policy to apply to users that logon to a specific computer.

Comment: **Is there a way to set up a GPO that will work for all users, but only when they log into this specific TS02 server?** - Yes. You need to configure loopback policy processing.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for the quick responces.
It was indeed the missing [loopback processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/group-policy/loopback-processing-of-group-policy), exactly as written in the comments. Just added this setting to my GPO and it worked like a charm.

thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a WMI Filter using a query like this:

```
Select * From Win32_ComputerSystem Where Name = "TS02"
```

Maybe this How-to can be helpful:
[Create WMI Filters for the GPO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj717288(v=ws.11))

There is plenty of stuff like this around there to dig into.